# Google Vision API not detecting any languages

Tags: ocr, google-cloud-vision

#### Summary

We are processing a document through Google Vision API to generate OCR from the document. However, the Cloud Vision API's text recognition feature is intermittently not recognizing any languages in a document -- even in documents that are 100% a single language.

#### What have we tried

While the [OCR Language Support documentation,](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/languages) recommends not supplying language hints while using `DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION` in order to gain full, auto-detected language detection, we have tried supplying the language hint of the known language but still no languages are detected.

Additionally, if we take the OCR output that was generating via Cloud Vision and pass that to Google Translate, Cloud Translation, or Amazon Comprehend, they all return the desired language.

#### Example

Using [this document as an example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_QOxwNKwJXsdMxIC4evvhFxLdj8FcVji/view?usp=sharing) and with the following code (some code removed for brevity/security), Google Cloud Vision does not detect any languages.

```js
const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision').v1;

const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient(authOptions());

const inputConfig = {
  mimeType: 'application/pdf',
  gcsSource: {
    uri: 'our-gcsSource',
  },
};

const features = [{ type: 'DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION' }];

const request = {
  requests: [
    {
      inputConfig,
      features,
    },
  ],
};

const [operation] = await client.asyncBatchAnnotateFiles(request);

// Additional code removed for brevity
```

Comment: Can you share a bit more about your use case why you need the language in the response? In this example, you know the language ahead of time, but for other files are you saying you don't know the language but you need to know it?

Comment: @Brendan Thanks for the question. That is correct -- we do not know the language ahead of time; the goal is to use this language detection to identify the possible languages and handle that output accordingly.